# What is the longest possible Parade?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-optimization, card-games

In the card game [Parade](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/56692/parade), the main mechanic has players build a chain of cards (a "parade") from a special deck. I've reproduced a simplified version of the rules below ([original rules here](https://images.zmangames.com/filer_public/57/a5/57a5d603-42ce-4487-9583-1c8b468eb639/zm1201_parade_rules.pdf)).

- The deck consists of $k=6$ suits, with each suit having values ranging from $a=0$ to $b=10$. In total, there are 66 cards.
- Initially, the parade is empty.
- Cards are added to the end of the parade one-by-one. Duplicates are not allowed (as we only have a single deck).
- In order to be able to add a card of value $x$ and suit $s$ to the end of the parade, the following 2 criteria both need to be satisfied:

  - Apart from the last $x$ cards of the parade, no other card can have value less than or equal to $x$.
  - Apart from the last $x$ cards of the parade, no other card can have suit $s$.

In other words, all cards already in the parade that have value $\le x$ or suit $s$ must have been placed in the last $x$ cards.
(In the original game, non-matching cards would be removed from the parade. I chose to instead disallow placing cards which would lead to this, in order to simplify the problem.)

Now my question is: what is the longest possible parade we can achieve?

For the original version of the game ($k=6,a=0,b=10$) I have used brute force to arrive at an answer of **25**.
I am interested in finding an analytical solution, and in particular how it varies for different values of $k,a,b$.

Comment: @RobPratt Yes, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with length $25$ for $k=6,a=0,b=10$, obtained via integer linear programming:

```
    x  s
 1 10  6
 2 10  3 
 3 10  1
 4  9  3
 5  9  6
 6  8  3
 7  8  6
 8  7  6
 9  7  3
10  7  1
11  8  1
12  9  1
13  9  2
14  8  2
15  7  2
16  4  2
17  5  2
18  4  5
19  6  2
20  5  5
21  3  5
22  6  5
23  0  4
24  3  4
25  2  4
```

My formulation uses binary decision variables $y_{x,s,p}$ to indicate whether card $(x,s)$ appears in position $p$.

Here are maximum lengths for other instances:
\begin{matrix}
k & a & b & \text{maximum} \\
\hline
1 & 0 & 10 & 11 \\
2 & 0 & 10 & 11 \\
3 & 0 & 10 & 16 \\
4 & 0 & 10 & 20 \\
5 & 0 & 10 & 22 \\
6 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
6 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
6 & 0 & 2 & 6 \\
6 & 0 & 3 & 9 \\
6 & 0 & 4 & 11 \\
6 & 0 & 5 & 13 \\
6 & 0 & 6 & 16 \\
6 & 0 & 7 & 18 \\
6 & 0 & 8 & 20 \\
6 & 0 & 9 & 23 \\
\end{matrix}

Comment: The multiple 0's at the end are not valid - after you put down the first one, you are not allowed to put the second one down because it violates the first condition. Let me know if that makes sense or if I need to clarify the rules further. In particular, one thing that might be unintuitive is that the $x$ in the conditions is the same $x$ on the card that you're trying to put down (hence isn't constant across the parade).

Comment: @apilat Thank you for the clarification.  I have corrected my formulation.